# Python: how to mapping label into new column based from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I've been searching around for a while now, but I can't seem to find the answer to this small problem.

I have this code to make a function for match data between from df_mall and df in column sample2, and the result show in new columns, if the data in the sample2/note column is in the data df_mall, then the result column will show label 1, otherwise 0.

```
mall_list = ['AMBON',
            'BANDUNG', 'BEKASI', 'BOGOR',
             'CIREBON',
             'DENPASAR',
             'GARUT',
             'JAKARTA',
             'KARAWANG', 'KUDUS',
             'MATARAM',
             'PALEMBANG',  
             'SAMARINDA', 'SURABAYA']
df_mall = pd.DataFrame(mall_list) 

df = {'Name':['al', 'el', 'naila', 'dori','jlo'],
    'living':['Alvando','Georgia GG','Newyork NY','Indiana IN','Florida FL'],
    'sample2':['BOGOR','GARUT','AMBON','WONOSOBO','SRAGEN'],
    'note':['KOTA','KAB','KOTA','WILAYAH','DAERAH']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

and I'm trying to make process, but didn't works

```
df['MALL_RESULT'] = 0
df = df.reset_index()
df.drop(['index'], axis=1, inplace=True)

for keys, i in enumerate(df.sample2):
    index = keys
    if i in (df_mall):
        df.loc[df.index == index, 'MALL'] = 1

df.loc[df.note == 'DAERAH', 'MALL'] = 1
df = df.reset_index()
```

But I am actually expecting this output with the simple code

```
  index Name     living     sample2    note    MALL_RESULT
0   0   al      Alvando      BOGOR     KOTA         1
1   1   el      Georgia GG   GARUT     KAB          1
2   2   naila   Newyork NY   AMBON     KOTA         1
3   3   dori    Indiana IN   WONOSOBO  WILAYAH      0
4   4   jlo     Florida FL   SRAGEN    DAERAH       1
```

Comment: Why is the last row 1?

Comment: because the 'note' column has 'DAERAH' so it includes 1

Comment: But DAERAH isn't in the mall_list? Or am I misreading

Comment: Yes, it's not in the mall list, but I want to add it manually from a different column

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
res = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['sample2'] in list(df_mall[0]) or row['note'] in list(df_mall[0]):
        res.append(1)
    else:
        res.append(0)
df['result'] = res
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are constraints not given in the question you don't need to turn `mall_list` into a dataframe. Using list comprehension you can create the dataframe column you're seeking.

```
df['MALL_RESULT'] = [1 if sample in mall_list or item in mall_list else 0 for sample, item in zip(df['sample2'], df['note'])]
```

If you do need `mall_list` to become a dataframe you can use the same logic

```
df['MALL_RESULT'] = [1 if sample in list(df_mall[0]) or item in list(df_mall[0]) else 0 for sample, item in zip(df['sample2'], df['note'])]
```

Comment: how to make some conditions like i want  label 1 if in df['note'] == 'DAERAH'

Comment: df['cond'] = df['note'] == 'DAERAH'

Comment: df['cond'] = df['cond'].astype(int)